# How to make space between 2 Iframes

Tags: iframe

I am trying to create bit of space between 2 iframes located at the bottom of this webpage here:

http://flyfishing.reviewthetruth.com/fly-fishing-gifts/fly-fishing-gifts.php

The Amazon book offers at the very bottom require a space between them. Any ideas gratefully received.

thanks

Angus

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

Add CSS style to the iframe tag like this:

margin-right: 15px;

Comment: Another suggestion: encapsulate each 'iframe' with a 'div' like so: `<div><iframe>...</iframe></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding 1 or two blank space (`&nbsp;`) or using CSS:

```
      <style type="text/css">
          iframe { margin: 15px; }
      </style>
```